# "found struct `ThereIsNoIteratorInRepetition`" when trying to repeat over a vector using `quote!`

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to create a `Vec` of `TokenStream`s, and then use that list in another `quote!` macro:

```rust
    let list: Vec<_> = some_data
        .iter()
        .map(
            |item| {
                quote!{/*...*/}
            },
        )
        .collect();

    let generated = quote! {
        fn hello_world() {
            #(list);*
        }
    };
```

However, when compiling this, I'm getting this error:

```
expected struct `HasIterator`, found struct `ThereIsNoIteratorInRepetition`
```

From [the macro's documentation](https://docs.rs/quote/1.0.9/quote/macro.quote.html), it seems that `TokenStream` should be valid in an interpolation, since it implements the `ToTokens` trait. Also, the list is a `Vec`, which is also explicitly allowed to be used in the loop interpolation.

Why am I getting the `ThereIsNoIteratorInRepetition` error when I am clearly using a valid iterator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```rust
#(list);*
```

Should be

```rust
#(#list);*
```

I missed the inner interpolation `#` in the repetition interpolation, and it was driving me crazy for hours. Leaving this here in case anybody runs into the same thing.

I guess `ThereIsNoIteratorInRepetition` means that no interpolation was found in the repetition, when I originally thought it meant that the interpolation was parsed correctly, but was not accepted as an iterator.